# Image hash paramater doubling up when inside a link

Tags: media-library

We have an image in Sitecore that needs to be rendered with a link wrapping it.  When the HTML renders the hash parameter is being added twice so we're getting errors in the Sitecore log about the value not matching.  Has anyone seen this issue or gotten a fix for it?  When rendered outside the link it renders properly, so my thought is the image is running through the pipeline twice.

Link

```
<a href="http://www.facebook.com/"><img src="/-/media/social/icon-facebook.svg?la=en&amp;hash=3B0EC93CDA5F46F4775B87A46B833E56E6981CB6&amp;hash=3B0EC93CDA5F46F4775B87A46B833E56E6981CB6" alt="Facebook" /></a>
```

View

```
@Html.Sitecore().Field("Facebook Link", new {text = Html.Sitecore().Field("Facebook")})
```

Sitecore 8.2 Update 5

Thanks

Comment: have you tried to generate the value first and then use it in `text` setter?

Comment: I have just tried that and am getting the same output.  I've also tried disabling all the custom pipelines just to make sure nothing there was doing anything.

Comment: Have you checked for any parameters on the image itself on the media library?
Does it happen with every image or just this one?

Comment: It happens with other images as well.  I've just been able to reproduce the issue with a clean Sitecore instance and have filed a ticket with support.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sitecore support was able to replicate the issue and have provided a fix.  Ask for support package 97023 if you're having this issue.